# Keycloak-angular obtain token for other client

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have the following components in my application:

- self hosted keycloak server
- backend REST-API (resource-server)
- frontend angular application

The keycloak server is configured to have 2 clients. One public client(angular app) and one confidential client(REST-API) with authorization services. The angular app needs to load the permissions of the backend to show different UI based on the permissions of the user. One way to obtain the required permissions is to use the token_endpoint like so:

```
this.http
      .get<{ token_endpoint: string }>(
        `/auth/realms/${realm}/.well-known/uma2-configuration`,
      )
      .pipe(
        flatMap(config =>
          this.http.post(
            config.token_endpoint,
            `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket&audience=${backendClientId}`,
            {
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
```

If I decode the JWT in the returned access_token I can obtain the correct permissions.
To do this, I would need a library to decode JWTs and implement the refreshing of this token myself. I have not found any documentation on how to do this with the keycloak-angular or keycloak-js libraries.

Is this the intended way to obtain the list of permissions associated with the user and another client?
And if it is, how do I implement this using the provided libraries?

Comment: I looked at this video when I was working with keycloak-angular integration : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5n0DhOdLxPc . PS it's not in english, but steps are the same.

Comment: I don't speak french so it would be super useful if you could provide a timestamp in that video wich addresses my problem. Just so you know: the authentication and authorization is working, but the frontend does not know which endpoints it can access.

Comment: How I implemented user roles and permission was that, once user logs in using keycloak, we can get the access token from keycloak. This token can be parsed with the keycloak-js inbuilt support. That token will contain data like user roles etc

Comment: Yes, the access token includes the realm roles of the user, but the permissions are specific to the backend client and are not included in the initial access token which is returned by the keycloak library.

Comment: Does your angular app know who is currently accessing? You mentioned that it's public. Does it have login function?

Comment: Well I use the authorization code flow for authentication. So angular redirects to the keycloak login page and keycloak redirects back after a successful login.

Comment: Ok, I've done same too. But regarding getting permission from backend - are you using some custom role mgmt logic in your backend? For my angular app, what I had done to differentiate between different set of users, was to assign them roles when creating those users in keycloak. So, that when I get the access token from keycloak, it contains that data.

Comment: I need a more complex permission management system than roles. As I stated in the question, I am using the authorization services (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/). The resources, permissions and policies are automatically created by the backend using the Keycloak API. A role based system is not enough to enforce all the permissions that I require.

Comment: Ok. Are the permissions created by the backend saved on your DB or are they saved in the keycloak server?

Comment: They are saved in Keycloak.

Comment: So, you want your backend to load these permission data from keycloak and return them to Angular app via an API call?

Comment: No...I want to load them from the keycloak server! As stated in the question I am able to do this with the provided code, but I would need to decode the JWT myself and manage the refreshing of the token. I don't want to write this logic, so I'm asking how to do it with the keycloak-js or keycloak-angular lib.

Comment: If you are using keycloak-js library, then you have access to a method called 'userInfo'. This might be helpful in getting the data(along with the permissions etc) associated with the user who's logged in.

Comment: So you are okey just reading your access token? As far as I understood you've got extra claims info into it. The access token is base64 encoded, so it should be enough to read it and decode using standard [JS functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob).

Comment: Yeah in theory that would be enough, but what about validating the access token signature? Wouldn't it be bad practice to just accept the payload without validation?